# Weird error when trying to publish kotlin MMP dependency to Maven Central

Tags: kotlin, gradle, github-actions

I tried to update my dependency on maven central after I changed some things on the build system. The publishing normally goes with Github Actions, but now I get a weird error which I don't get locally.

Log: https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/runs/3914924573?check_suite_focus=true
Build File: https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/master/build.gradle.kts

Comment: It worked before but I added the gradle thing with buildSrc

Comment: >In plugin 'org.gradle.maven-publish' type 'org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository' property 'credentials.username' doesn't have a configured value

Comment: Are you sure you've correctly set [respectful](https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/ef78dce1d585c50e55e9c380ee34c25ef3fefbb3/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Versions.kt#L26-L28) [environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables)?

Actually, it's recommended to use [encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) for this...

Comment: Yes I mean it worked before I added the buildSrc thing with the Versions. Locally works but the files don't get signed. As you can see in the github action log there are the environment variables

Comment: Thats what I used before: https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/0.4/build.gradle.kts
I don't know if it still works

Comment: I mean you can see he gets the enviroment variables from the secrets and they are there https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/master/.github/workflows/release.yml

Comment: In `0.4` you [were using](https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/94a8c31d19010a964fbcaf00dc21071e285ab0e7/build.gradle.kts#L69-L70) `OSSRH_USERNAME` and `OSSRH_PASSWORD` envs, in `master` you're [using](https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/ef78dce1d585c50e55e9c380ee34c25ef3fefbb3/build.gradle.kts#L62-L63) `SONATYPE_USERNAME` and `SONATYPE_PASSWORD` (defined as envs in buildSrc). I don't see them to be set in [release.yml](https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/master/.github/workflows/release.yml#L9-L14)

Comment: Actually, `SONATYPE_USERNAME` and `SONATYPE_PASSWORD` [were referred in 0.4](https://github.com/jan-tennert/DiscordKM/blob/94a8c31d19010a964fbcaf00dc21071e285ab0e7/build.gradle.kts#L2-L3) as well, but they were unused

Comment: That was the issue, thank you! I don't know when I would have seen that!